# MSBuild fails to find directory with huge sub-directory

Tags: msbuild

I want to create an MSBuild item that includes all files in a sub-directory, recursively, except the "node_modules" directory and a few others.

```
<MyItem Include="MyDir\**\*.*" Exclude="MyDir\node_modules\**\*.*;MyDir\tmp\**\*.*" />
```

In the build log I see this:

```
Input file "MyDir\**\*.*" does not exist.
```

When I delete the "node_modules" directory it works. I suspect MSBuild fails to process it because it contains over 30,000 files and a deep sub-directory structure. Is there a way I can work around this without listing all the sub-directories I want to include, which may change from time to time?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out a way using another target with CreateItems:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <InputDirs Include="MyDir" />
    <InputExcludedSubDirs Include="MyDir\tmp;MyDir\node_modules" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="PrepareForMyTarget">
    <ItemGroup>
        <InputSubDirs Include="$([System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories(&quot;%(InputDirs.Identity)&quot;))" Exclude="@(InputExcludedSubDirs)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <CreateItem Include="%(InputSubDirs.Identity)\**\*.*">
       <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="Inputs" />
   </CreateItem>
</Target>

<Target Name="MyRealTarget" DependsOnTargets="PrepareForMyTarget">
     ... use Inputs item here as normal ...
</Target>
```